# Interrupt download which uses dataInputStream

Tags: android, download, inputstream, datainputstream

Have a pretty simple code for download file.

```
class Downloader {
private static Downloader Dinstance = null;
private boolean isAborted = false;

void setAborted(boolean isAborted) {
    isAborted = true;
}

int getAborted() {
    return isAborted;
}

static Downloader getInstance(@NonNull Context context) {
        if (Dinstance == null)
            Dinstance = new Downloaderr(context.getApplicationContext());
        return Dinstance;
    }

private Downloader() {
    ...
    }

function download() {
    ...
    try {
            URL url = new URL(RequestedURL);
            InputStream inputStream = url.openStream();
            DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(inputStream);
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(FileName);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = dataInputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                if (getAborted()) {
                    Log.d(static_variables.TAG, "Aborting 1");
                    fileOutputStream.close();
                    Log.d(static_variables.TAG, "Aborting 2");
                    dataInputStream.close();
                    Log.d(static_variables.TAG, "Aborting 3");
                    inputStream.close();
                    Log.d(static_variables.TAG, "All closed");                        
                    file.delete();
                    downloadFinished = true;
                    Log.d(static_variables.TAG, "Returning");
                    return false;
                    }
            fileOutputStream.close();
            dataInputStream.close();
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            downloadFinished = true;
            return false;
        }
    ...
    }
}
```

In MainActivity

First button listener(start download):

```
function onClick() {
   new Thread(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
           Downloader.getInstance().download(...);
           }
       }).start();
   }
```

Second button listener:

```
function onClick() {
   Downloader.getInstance().setAborted(true);
   }
```

Download going in thread.
In logs time for `dataInputStream.close();` is biggest. And other research shows that streams won't close before file will be fully downloaded.

How I can terminate `InputStream` in progress?

Comment: Please show your full code and where you stop/abort the downloading as well.

Comment: I've rewrote code. It's not my full code. But structure is same. I actually don't see reason why it needed. Because log messages in `logcat` appears. As I think structure is working, problem with `InputStream` termination

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During research I found two things.

1. Download aborts with this approach, but there is a buffer and for small files(songs, in my case) it's almost untrackable. For 500Mb file download, when you press abort on 15Mb downloaded, then after 16-17 it will stop.
2. If you want(as I am) terminate download faster, then you should use another approach. When starting Thread, save pointer int variable.

```
Thread threadDownload = new Thread(...);
threadDownload.start();
```

then abort using

```
threadDownload.interrupt();
```

Beware. You'll need remove temporary file by yourself. File which you use in `OutputStream`.

You also will have some buffer overhead, but it will be not 1-2Mb, but 200-300Kb.